# Cascading Ad-units in DFP Small Business

Tags: javascript, advertisement-server, google-ad-manager

I have 2 ad units:

1. Homepage banner
2. ROS Banner (run of site)

Basically, I want to find a way to server ROS Banner when Homepage Banner doesn't have anything to serve so the impressions are wasted.

I found this, but was wondering if anyone knew a better way:

http://gam.ingraye.com/cascade/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer, there isn't another way.

Comment: The link you posted to the solution doesn't work anymore. Do you have a working link? I'm interested to see what the solution was.